# Ordenar elementos de um dicionario python

Tags: python-3.x

Olá, eu tenho um arquivo csv, do qual faço a leitura para um dicionario, o arquivo é o seguinte:

```
maquina,num,projeto,var,reg,nome,valor
br,1,1809123,float,4637,teste1
br,1,1809123,float,4639,teste2
br,2,1809123,float,4641,teste1
br,2,1809123,float,4643,teste2
br,2,1809123,int,4107,teste3
al,1,1809123,int,4186,teste4
al,2,1809123,float,4645,teste4
```

O meu dicionário fica assim(com a aquisição de valores):

```
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '1'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4637'), ('nome', 'teste1'), ('valor', 1.1869791746139526)])
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '1'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4639'), ('nome', 'teste2'), ('valor', 0.1163330078125)])
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4641'), ('nome', 'teste1'), ('valor', 1077.43994140625)])
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4643'), ('nome', 'teste2'), ('valor', 124.00007629394531)])
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'int'), ('reg', '4107'), ('nome', 'teste3'), ('valor', 228)])
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'al'), ('num', '1'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'int'), ('reg', '4186'), ('nome', 'teste4'), ('valor', 250)])
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'al'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4645'), ('nome', 'teste4'), ('valor', 0.0)])
```

Agora eu preciso ordenar os dados para posteriormente gravá-los em um banco de dados, por isso criei a seguinte funcão:

```
def preparar_dados(dados_modbus,maquina,num):
registradores = {}
for dado in dados_modbus:
    if dado['maquina'] == maquina and dado['num'] == num:
        registradores.update({dado['maquina']:dado['num'],dado['nome']:dado['valor']})
return registradores
```

Nesta função eu forneço o dicionario, o nome da maquina e o numero dela. Mas eu gostaria que o programa fizesse isso sem que eu precisasse dizer para ele o nome e num da maquina. Quero uma logica para mudar a própria funçao para não precisar informar "maquina" e "num". O resultado deste novo código seria o seguinte:

```
{'al': '1', 'teste6': 0}
{'br': '1', 'teste1': 0.952343761920929, 'teste2': 0.0997314453125}
{'al': '2', 'teste7': 0.0}
{'br': '2', 'teste3': 1077.43994140625, 'teste4': 104.00007629394531, 'teste5': 0}
```

Aguardo uma ajuda nesta questão.

Comment: Qual é a regra de ordenação?

Comment: "maquina" e "num" são os valores que combinados devem ser únicos, no momento estou informando eles para a função manualmente, mas queria muito que o programa fizesse isso automaticamente. Não sei se ordenação é a palavra correta, preciso que a função retorne como resultado os valores que coloquei no final da questão. Sem precisar disto aqui:    `dados_br1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"br","1")
    dados_al1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"al","1")` Deveria ser algo assim:    `dados_ordenados = preparar_dados(dados_modbus)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro criei uma lista com os dicionários que você colocou acima.

```
lista = [
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '1'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4637'), ('nome', 'teste1'), ('valor', 1.1869791746139526)]),
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '1'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4639'), ('nome', 'teste2'), ('valor', 0.1163330078125)]),
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4641'), ('nome', 'teste1'), ('valor', 1077.43994140625)]),
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4643'), ('nome', 'teste2'), ('valor', 124.00007629394531)]),
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'br'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'int'), ('reg', '4107'), ('nome', 'teste3'), ('valor', 228)]),
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'al'), ('num', '1'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'int'), ('reg', '4186'), ('nome', 'teste4'), ('valor', 250)]),
OrderedDict([('maquina', 'al'), ('num', '2'), ('projeto', '1809123'), ('var', 'float'), ('reg', '4645'), ('nome', 'teste4'), ('valor', 0.0)])
]
```

Em seguida você pode percorrer por toda a lista e organizar da forma que tinha sugerido sem precisar informar a maquina e numero

```
registro = []
temp = []
for lst in lista:
    if (lst['maquina'], lst['num']) in temp:    
        count = temp.index((lst['maquina'], lst['num']))
        registro[count].update({lst['nome']:lst['valor']})
    else:
        temp.append((lst['maquina'], lst['num']))
        registro.append({})
        count = temp.index((lst['maquina'], lst['num']))        
        registro[count][lst['maquina']] = lst['num']
        registro[count][lst['nome']] = lst['valor']
```

Por fim para manter a ordem do dicionario tu pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
temp_sort = sorted(temp, key=lambda x: x[0])
for ts in temp_sort:
    count = temp.index(ts)
    print(registro[count])
```

O print fica da seguinte forma:

```
{'al': '1', 'teste4': 250}
{'al': '2', 'teste4': 0.0}
{'br': '1', 'teste1': 1.1869791746139526, 'teste2': 0.1163330078125}
{'br': '2', 'teste1': 1077.43994140625, 'teste2': 124.00007629394531, 'teste3': 228}
```

Comment: Muito bom.... exatamente o que preciso, vou estudar o que cada parte faz, porque sou novato em python. Me ajudou muito;